# Django/JSON: Finding Species in Range, Printing in JSON

Tags: python, json, django

I am working on a Species Recommendation tool that will find all of the trees in a GPS range, average out the trees of allowed species, and then return the results in a JSON dict that can be parsed and read out.

I was working with folks from Code for SF who were using the K Nearest Neighbors algorithm, which was really nice, but kept crashing the application and was only pulling from a csv I uploaded, rather than the database of trees and planting sites I created.

Is there a way to implement K Nearest Neighbors to search my database that's better than using latitude__range and longitude__range? This is my current view:

```
def sg_species_guide_latlong_json(request, latitude=1, longitude=1):
    min_latitude = decimal.Decimal(latitude)
    min_latitude -= decimal.Decimal(0.01)
    max_latitude = decimal.Decimal(latitude)
    max_latitude += decimal.Decimal(0.01)
    min_longitude = decimal.Decimal(longitude)
    min_longitude -= decimal.Decimal(0.01)
    max_longitude = decimal.Decimal(longitude)
    max_longitude += decimal.Decimal(0.01)

    response = JsonResponse(dict(species_list=list(RecommendedSpecies.objects.values(
                                        "species__id_species", "species__trees_of_species__condition__score", "species__name_scientific", 
                                    ).filter(
                                        Q(species__trees_of_species__planting_site__coord_lat__range=[min_latitude, max_latitude]), 
                                        Q(species__trees_of_species__planting_site__coord_long__range=[min_longitude, max_longitude]), 
                                        ).annotate(avg_condition=(Avg('species__trees_of_species__condition__score')),
                                        num_trees=(Count('species__trees_of_species'))).order_by('-avg_condition'))))

    return response
```

It's VERY slow, especially for what should be an AJAX/JSON call.

In addition, I want to print out the results in a format that contains the species name, number of trees, and average condition. Sorting that is easy in my view, but printing it out in JSON has been really tough. The dicts that JSON returns look like this:

{"species_list": [{"num_trees": 102, "species__trees_of_species__condition__score": 5, "species__id_species": 88, "avg_condition": 5.0, "species__name_scientific": "Arbutus x marina"}, {"num_trees": 828, "species__trees_of_species__condition__score": 4, "species__id_species": 88, "avg_condition": 4.0, "species__name_scientific": "Arbutus x marina"}]}
I would like to parse each object and display the scientific name, average condition, and number of trees.

Currently this is my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function if_gmap_updateInfoWindow()
            {
                var lng = gmapmarker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6)
                var lat = gmapmarker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6)
                infoWindow.setContent("Longitude: " + lng + "<br>" + "Latitude: " + lat);
                document.getElementById("location-info").innerHTML = 'Lat / Long: ' + lat + ' x ' + lng;

                // Call the model api
                // TODO consts
                $.ajax({    
                    url: '/species-guide/json/' + lat + '/' + lng,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'get',
                    success: function(response){

                        document.getElementById("species-recommendations").innerHTML = response['species_list'].join('<br>')

                        console.log(response)
                    }
                })
            } // end of if_gmap_bindInfoWindow
        </script>
```

which returns a list of [object Object] instead of keys & values

I would love to have it spit out keys & values using something like this:

var species_recs = response['species_list']\

```
document.getElementById("species-recommendations").innerHTML =

species_recs.forEach(species => {
    Object.keys(species).forEach(key => {
        '<pre>' + species[key] + '</pre><br>';
    })
})
```

but that returns undefined. Is there a better way to get it to yield the data?

Comment: why don't you just use geodjango?

Comment: i'm not very familiar with it and the tutorial sites that i've seen have made it sound like i'd have to dump the entire database and rebuild from scratch to use it. if i can find the right examples i'd be happy to go that route